# Static image for 3d Object (Swift AR)

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, augmented-reality

i just wanna know how can i make my SceneKit object to be static like a regular 2d image instead of making it shape like a sphere. I'm quite new to AR so i don't really know how to programme it well. Thank you!

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class Ship: SCNNode {
    let radius : CGFloat = 0.11
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: radius)
        self.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
        self.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false

        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategory.ship.rawValue
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategory.bullets.rawValue

        // add texture
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "innierevised")
        self.geometry?.materials  = [material, material, material, material, material, material]
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a SCNPlane and use its material property to assign it an image :

```
// Compute Material
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.isDoubleSided = false
material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "innierevised") 
material.diffuse.contentsTransform = 
SCNMatrix4Translate(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(-1, 1, 1), 1, 0, 0)
// This is if your image is flipped vertically (as SceneKit coordinate system is different from UIKit one)
```

Then :

```
// Create Plane
let newPoi = SCNPlane(width: radius, height: radius)
newPoi.materials = [material]
let newPoiNode = SCNNode(geometry: newPoi)
newPoiNode.position = // your SCNVector3 expected position
newPoiNode.constraints = [SCNBillboardConstraint()] // Look towards camera
```

Comment: Thanks mate it works! but there's one tiny problem. Why is it when i run it on my iPad instead, the camera doesn't work? https://ibb.co/iUVQdm

Comment: Ok nvm i just figured it out because my iPad is using A8 chip. Theres no way AR can work on A8 chip right